# How do I troubleshoot DDNS forwarding problem?

Tags: dhcp, dnssec

Running BIND 9.10.3-P4-RedHat-9.10.3-12.P4.fc23 and DHCP Server 4.3.3-P1. DNS Zones report no errors and appear to work (dig, nslookup, nsupdate, dnssec, rpz, etc.). DHCP starts up without complaint, assigns ip, but log file messages similar to: "Unable to add forward map from pc2.blkdiamonds.lan. to 10.0.2.63" appears for each client.

I've read man pages, forum posts, dhcp-users lists and archives but I haven't been able to determine what's different in my configuration that causes the DHCP server to send the client's forward map back to the client?

Any ideas will greatly be appreciated.

```
DHCP.CONF (partial) is a follows:
default-lease-time 600;
max-lease-time 7200;
ddns-updates on;
update-static-leases on;
use-host-decl-names on;
ddns-update-style interim;
authoritative;
include "/etc/named/_blkdiamonds.ddns.update.key";
log-facility local7;
ping-check true;
ddns-domainname "blkdiamonds.lan.";
ddns-rev-domainname "in-addr.arpa.";
server-identifier roxie.blkdiamonds.lan;
local-address 10.0.2.254;
one-lease-per-client on;
do-forward-updates true;
....
shared-network benu {
    ignore client-updates;
    deny unknown-clients;
    # wr0
    subnet 10.0.2.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
        authoritative;
        ignore client-updates;
        deny unknown-clients;
        ddns-domainname "blkdiamonds.lan.";
        ddns-rev-domainname "in-addr.arpa.";
        range 10.0.2.160 10.0.2.167;
        option broadcast-address 10.0.2.255;
        option domain-name-servers 10.0.2.254;
        option ntp-servers 10.0.2.254;
        option routers 10.0.2.254;
        option time-servers 10.0.2.254;

        group {
            host pc2-wifi.blkdiamonds.lan {
                hardware ethernet 88:25:2c:bc:11:1a;
                fixed-address 10.0.2.63;
                ddns-hostname "Roy-fallen-pc2-wifi";
                }
...
Another subnet
```

Comment: This looks similar, in case it helps: http://serverfault.com/q/564278/293440

Comment: add more related logs in order to help us diagnose the issue, if you're still having it.